# #define に関して

Tags: c++, preprocessor

今、`C++`のマクロを自力で展開しようとしています。
そこで、"#define"　を見つけたのですが、このようになっていました。

```
#ifndef  OuHolder_h
#define  OuHolder_h
```

このような"`#define`"は「`OuHolder_h`が定義されている」ということを表すようなのですが、
これをどう展開すればよいか分かりません。
どうすればいいでしょうか?

Comment: マクロ展開を手作業で行いたいとのことですが、
プリプロセス全体を手作業で行うつもりではないと想像できます。
おそらく関数様の(引数のある)マクロのみ手作業で展開することを
意図しているのではないでしょうか。
この場合、対象の#defineは単なる定義なのでつまり、関数様のマクロではないので、展開はできません。
まず、関数様のマクロと置換用のマクロ定義、その他のプリプロセス命令等を
見極める知識が必要となります。

Answer (score 4):

何をされようとしているのかは分かりませんが、以下は俗にインクルードガードと呼ばれるものです。説明には書かれていませんが、そのファイルの末尾に『endif』も居るはずです。

```
#ifndef  OuHolder_h
#define  OuHolder_h
// 省略
#endif
```

まず、『ifdef』と『ifndef』は違いますので、ご注意を...

『ifndef』から『endif』内は『OuHolder_h』が定義されていなかった場合にのみ実行されます。
なので、2行目の『define』で『OuHolder_h』が定義されると、『ifndef』から『endif』内は実行されません。

これは、同じheader fileを複数ファイルから読んでいる場合に、何度も同じheader fileを読み込まないようにするためのものです。

まずは、簡単なことから理解して徐々にやりたいことを試して行くことをオススメします。

Answer (score 1):

言い換えるなら `#ifndef` はその定義がまだ定義されていなければ、という意味です。

そのため、定義されていなければ定義する、ということになります。

Answer (score 1):

もし、自力展開が目的なのではなく、プリプロセス完了後のソースを見たいというだけなら、コンパイラがそのオプションを持っていることがありますので、それを使うという手があります。
例えば、VC++ (コマンド名: `cl`) なら `/E` 、`g++` や `clang++` では `-E` で、プリプロセス結果を出力することができます。

Answer (score 1):

基礎的なところを書くと

```
#ifndef  OuHolder_h  // もしここまででOuHolder_hというものが定義されて「いないなら」#endifまでのソースコードを有効にする.
#define  OuHolder_h  // OuHolder_hというマクロを定義する。この行以降OuHolder_hと書かれればこのマクロのこと

#endif
```

ということとなる。なので

```
#include <iostream>

#define Macro1
#ifndef Macro1
    // #ifndefの前でMacro1が#defineされているから、ここはプリプロセスもコンパイルもされない.
    #define SUM( x, y ) (x + y)
    void print_hello(){ std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl; }
#endif

int main(){
    int x = SUM( 1, 2 );  // SUMは定義されていない。コンパイルエラー.
    print_hello();        // print_helloも同様に定義されていｔない。エラー.
}
```

であればコメントの通りコンパイルエラーとなり

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef Macro2
    // #ifndefの前で#define Macro2が書かれていないから、プリプロセスもコンパイルも行われる.
    #define SUM( x, y ) (x + y)
    void print_hello(){ std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl; }
#endif

int main(){
    int x = SUM( 1, 2 );  // 通る.
    print_hello();        // これも通る。Hello, World!とコンソールに出力される.
}
```

こちらは通るということになる。

ちなみに`#define OuHolder_h`という定義以降からは`OuHolder_h`という識別子がソースコードに記述されている個所は全部に置き換えるような形で展開する。実際には一切の空白も入れないだろうが。